# Is there a way in Windows 10 to convert a hexadecimal code to its symbol regardless of the program?

Tags: hex, symbols

I've read many pages that point out that many office applications allow for this by typing the code followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, but frequently, I want to insert a symbol when I'm not in one of those applications. Is there a universal way to achieve this?

The character map is useless, unless you have time to manually search through all the characters available.

Comment: Use your account to ask at [Super User](https://superuser.com/), they might know better (some Windows power-user tricks) . Stackoverflow is for **programming** questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the question at Super User, and basically, the response I got there was to use Alt codes for the symbols.  However, I discovered that, on the whole, these only work for the first 256 Alt codes.  So basically, the answer to my question is "No, there's not a good way."